# Count occurance of alternative values in key value pairs in python

Tags: python, count, key-value

I have a huge list of pairs of strings like:

```
data = [['1','A'],['2','B'],['1','C'],['2','B'],['3','C'],['1','A'],['2','C'],['1','A'],['1','D'],['3','C']]
```

In theory they should all be the keys and their matching values. Though in reality of my data they are not. For that reason I would like to count and order the most common combination in case the values differ to get the result like:

```
{'2': [('B', 2), ('C', 1)], '1': [('A', 3), ('C', 1), ('D', 1)]}
```

So I created a dict:

```
import collections
dc = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in data:
  dc[k].append(v)
```

This approach works as well though it seems a bit slower:

```
dc = {}
for k,v in data:
  dc.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
```

And then I perform the count in case the values are not the same:

```
{k:collections.Counter(v).most_common() for k,v in dc.items() if len(set(v))>1}
```

There are hundreds of thousands of pairs in my data so I wonder if there is a faster way how to count the number of the duplicates of the values? I'm open to use the tools like numpy or other scientific libraries, but I couldn't come up with any better method so far. Is there any alternative? I'm getting the data by `etree` from xml files so the original structure of the data can be modified for whatever kind of processing which would be the fastest.